# Python Simple OAuth access

Tags: python, oauth

I am trying to access a proprietary web service that has Oauth access. I have no experience with that and I am trying to use ;'requests' and 'requests_oauthlib'.

I have the following access data:

```
auth_url = 'https://foobar.url.com/oauth/token'  
data_url = 'https://foobar.url.com/rest/v1/aname/overview'

API_Key = 'Basic Y2xpY2tleS1hcHA6YXBwLWFjY2Vzcw=='

username ='ausername'  password = 'apassword' grant_type = 'password'
```

The API key should be put in the Header in the Field 'Authorization'

Any examples that fit the above would be appreciated. I cannot find any match with the requests_oauth docs.

Comment: I think that you should check the documentation of said web service how you access depends on how they have things setup.

Comment: Well, the above if what the doc says..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, requests_oauthlib hasn't provided a way to issue password grant type token. You can try [Authlib](https://authlib.org/), the client of Authlib has a similar API, check how to authenticate with password grant type:

https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/oauth2.html#oauth2session-for-password